# Assigning a variable to an integer converted parameter and using in html.erb file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, applicationcontroller

Basically I want to use parameters to store the values of these input fields as integers

```
<input type="number" name="happyquant" min="1" max="5" value="1" />
<input type="number" name="skyquant" min="1" max="5" value="1" class="bot"/>
```

This code is in another html.erb file so when i press submit I want it to transmit the values. Sorry for not clarifying this earlier. BTW the site im running it on is http://ipt-dynaman.c9.io/.
My controller

```
def receipt
render layout: 'cart'
params[:skyquant] = params[:skyquant].to_i
params[:happyquant] = params[:happyquant].to_i
a = params[:skyquant]*50
end
```

Where i want to display it

```
<div class="receipt-row">
   <% a %>
</div>
```

In all honesty I dont even know what I'm doing but I want to basically learn how to use variables like that in html.erb files. Specifically using this as an example.

Comment: use @a instance variable instead of 'a' and use @a in your html view.

Comment: <%= @a %> you missed '='

Answer (score 1):

For you to be able to use variable inside `html.erb` file, you must declare variable as instance variable, to display something from variable, you have to use `<%= ruby_code %>` instead of `<% ruby_code %>`

```
def receipt
 render layout: 'cart'
 params[:skyquant] = params[:skyquant].to_i
 params[:happyquant] = params[:happyquant].to_i
 @a = params[:skyquant]*50
 # variable with @ in front of name, are instance variables
end

<div class="receipt-row">
   <%= @a %>
</div>
```

When you use `<% %>` it evaluates ruby code, but will not display what this code returns, when you use `<%= %>` it will display result of code, your case value from `@a`

Comment: it's instance variable, not instant variable :)

Answer (score 0):

a is a local variable. They only exists within its scope (current block)

@a is an instance variable - and is available to all methods within the class.

In Ruby on Rails - declaring your variables in your controller as instance variables (@a) makes them available to your view.

read more here: http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.dk/2010/03/variables.html